# Ternary and cast as qsort argument

Tags: c

I'm trying to practice pointer to function but I don't understand the technique used.

Context:

```
char *lineptr[5000];
int strcmp (char *, char *);
int numcmp (char *, char *);`
```

The function prototype is:

```
void qsort ( void *lineptr[], int left, int right, int (*comp)(void *, void *));
```

I don't understand how the following call works:

```
qsort((void**)lineptr ,0 , nlines-1, (int(*)(void*,void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp));
```

Specifically this part:

```
(int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
```

The function prototype has only 4 argument whereas in the function call, there are 5 parameters and the 5th one is an equation. And this compiles without error.

At one point I assumed that it would assign either `numcomp` or `strcmp` to the function pointer `(*comp)` based the value of `numeric`. But what I don't understand is how will this assignment happens.

Comment: Wouldn't using an `int (*)(char *, char *)` instead of an `int (*)(const void *, const void *)` invoke undefined behaviour, at least the moment the function is called (C11 draft 6.3.2.3/8)?

Comment: There is no `const` here. Casting `char *` to `void *` will not cause any trouble here, they're both pointers of the same size. And since `lineptr` is a `char`-array, qsort will pass char pointers to the callback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only 4 arguments are passed, the 4th argument

```
(int (*)(void*, void*))(numeric ? numcmp : strcmp)
```

will either pass a pointer to the `numcmp` (if `numeric` is truthy) or a pointer to the `strcmp` function (if `numeric` is falsy).

`(int (*)(void*, void*))` is just a cast to the function signature to help the compiler, because the compiler is expecting `(int (*)(void*, void*))` as function pointer (see `qsort` function prototype) and you're passing in a pointer to `numcmp/strcmp` which is `(int (*)(char*, char*))`.

Comment: can you share me link where i can get detailed || complete `info on casting function pointer`..??

Comment: You can start [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html)

Answer (score 2):

There are only 4 arguments in:

```
qsort((void**)lineptr,0,nlines-1,(int(*)(void*,void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp));
```

Broken down to one-per-line, it looks like:

```
qsort((void**)lineptr,
      0,
      nlines-1,
      (int(*)(void*,void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp));
```

The last one seems to be the one that's confusing you.  The `?:` expression is selecting one of two functions with the same declared type:

```
numeric?numcmp:strcmp
```

This is then parenthesized (for precedence) and cast to a function pointer type that takes two `void *` arguments:

```
(int(*)(void*,void*))funcptr
```

The type in the cast operator is a pointer to a function that takes two `void *` arguments and returns an `int` result.

Answer (score 0):

The last argument to `qsort` is a bit complex.

```
qsort((void**)lineptr,0,nlines-1,(int(*)(void*,void*))(numeric?numcmp:strcmp));
//                               |<--        one argument                 -->
```

At the cost of more verbose code, you can simplify that line to

```
int(*compare_function)(void*,void*) = (int(*)(void*,void*))numcmp;
if ( !numeric )
{
   compare_function = (int(*)(void*,void*))strcmp;
}

qsort((void**)lineptr,0,nlines-1, compare_function);
```